# Viewport shader material is different from material preview

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, shaders

Greeting, I’m a newbie to blender. I’m creating material for a box. I created that material by viewing material preview in blender but, my material on my box is different from than previewer. I dunno what to do and I just want a material that shown in material previewer. Any bits of help is appreciated.[[image: node tree][1]]

[image: viewport shader and material preview]

Comment: can you share the blend file?

Comment: So you want to drop the rainbow coloring and make it black? You would need to just drop the bottom nodes starting with Geometry node. It seems the difference is caused by different viewing angles.

Answer (score 0):

I got what I excepted by changing coloramp node
[image]